# Python 2.7 - Regex match for string in multiple lines

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am new to Python and learning on how to match string with multiple lines.
Currently, this is the regex I am trying to match strings between Section One and Section Two, that I am expecting to match the conditions 1, 2 and 3 as explained in the regex101 link in [Regex to match multiple lines, same line, next line and do not match empty lines or do not match just empty new line](https://regex101.com/r/46mQMc/7/). Following regex matches the strings in same line and next line, but does not consider strings on multiple new lines

Not sure, what I am missing here. Any help is appreciated.

```
regex = re.compile(r'Section One:\s*([^\s].+?)\s*(?=[0-9](?:\.)(\s?)Section Two:)+', re.IGNORECASE | re.DOTALL)
```

Comment: Can you post a sample input and expected output in the question?

Comment: maybe the problem comes from the site. locally it works ok. but once you set the dotall flag you can simplify your regex `regex = re.compile(r'1. Section One:\n(.*?)\n2. Section Two', re.DOTALL)`

Comment: Rakesh, thanks for ur response. The expected output is in the regex101 link part of the question.

Comment: Thanks bobrobbob, i will give it a try with the simplified regex